# How to correctly obtain database values in custom attribute for validating IdentityRole?

Tags: c#, validation, razor, mvvm

I am working on a webapplication that has multiples roles and users. I made it in .NET Core 2 with the individual users accounts structure and the web application option (not mvc, so I am using MVVM with Razor Pages)

Currently, whenever I hit the 'edit' button for a user that I've displayed in a data table/gridview, it populates a form in the same view with all corresponding values from the database using a AJAX call in a form next to it.

It also populates a dropdown for the roles, it will be:

#### Populated dropdown

```
<label>Role</label>
<select class="form-control" id="roles" name="RoleId" asp-for="Input.RoleId">
    <option value="Admin">User</option>
    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
    <option value="User">User</option>
</select>
```

#### My Inputmodel

```
public class UsersModel : PageModel
{
    ... 

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public List<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }


    public UsersModel(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    } 

    public async Task<IactionResult> OnGet()
    {
       Roles = _dbContext.Roles.ToList();
    }

    public class UserModel
    { 
        ...

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Role")]
        public string RoleId { get; set; }
        ...
    }

}
```

#### My Post method

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAsync(UserModel model, string id)
{
    ...

   var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
   Task<IList<string>> rolesUser = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
   IdentityRole currentRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(rolesUser.Result.First());
   string selectedRole = model.RoleId;


   if (selectedRole != currentRole.Name)
   {     
       await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, currentRole.Name);
       await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, selectedRole);
   }

   await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
   return RedirectToPage(...);

   ...
}
```

This works properly. I am able to hit the save button and everything works. However, in this situation it's possible to edit the HTML value with a not existing role, for example:

```
<option value="Not existing">Example</option>
```

And it will crash immediately. So I'd like to validate the selected option on the server-side so avoid malicious actions such as this.

```
[RegularExpresson("^(Admin|Manager|User)*$)]
```

This fixes my problem, but is hardcoded and feels dirty. I'd like to compare it with database values. A custom attribute should do the deal, but all given examples on other posts didn't satisfy my needs in this case. They all show examples of the MVC-pattern, but not the MVVM-pattern. I am aware it's probably a way of code structure, but I am not that familiar with mvc, thus I am not able to convert those examples in my mvvm context.

## Attempt

What I've tried so far:

#### My ViewModel

```
 public class UserModel
 {  
      ... 

      [Required]
      [CheckRole(typeof(IdentityRole))]
      [Display(Name = "Role")]
      public string RoleId { get; set; }

      ...
 }
```

#### CheckRoleAttribute

```
public class CheckRoleAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public Type ObjectType { get; private set; }
    public CheckRoleAttribute(Type type)
    {
        ObjectType = type;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // I understand passed value is the given option from the option        to validate
        // I'd like to obtain my available roles here that are available from the database, so I can validate it and return the correct error message.
    }

 }
```

Again, I am using the MVVM-pattern and not the MVC-pattern.

## edit 1

```
 // My Attribute
 protected override ValidationResult IsValid(
        object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var context = (ApplicationDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(ApplicationDbContext));

        if (!context.Roles.Any(p => p.Name == value)) // changed 'p => p' to 'p => p.Name'
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }           

        return new ValidationResult($"The selected {value} doesn't exist.");


    }

    //My model
    [Required]
    [ValidateRole]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

## edit 2

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAsync(UserModel model, string id)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
        Task<IList<string>> rolesUser = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        IdentityRole currentRole = await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync(rolesUser.Result.First());
        string selectedRole = model.RoleId;



        if (user == null || !ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        ...

         if (selectedRole != currentRole.Name)
        {

            await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, currentRole.Name);
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, selectedRole);

        }

        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        return RedirectToPage(...);

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by IoC?

Comment: As far as my understanding of .net core webapplication (mvvm) with razor pages and identitystores, I am using Dependency Injections yes!